# FileSyncClient.pdb not loaded

Tags: windows, visual-studio, onedrive

how do I fix this? there is sometimes a notification whenever i shutdown my laptop. These are the details: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE54A888E3 (FileSyncClient.dll) in OneDrive.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCBpd.png)

i don't know how to fix it.